# How to force --document-private-items from Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

Is there a way of forcing private items documentation on docs build?

It can be done manually adding the doc flag `--document-private-items`, but I would like to force it in `Cargo.toml` level for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this not with `Cargo.toml` but cargo's config. In your project (or in `$CARGO_HOME` if you want this to apply for all of your projects) create `.cargo/config.toml` with following contents:

```ini
[build]
rustdocflags = ["--document-private-items"]
```

Here is the link to the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildrustdocflags).

Comment: I always forget about the config file. That was exactly what I needed, thanks!!

Comment: Actually somehow it doesn't work :S, tried with `cargo doc` and `cargo rustdoc`, seems like it do not read the flag.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't typo? It worked for me.

Comment: tripel checked because I thought it was the case, but it was correct @_@

Comment: What version of `cargo` you have? Do you use any cargo related env variables?

Comment: `1.64.0`, I am setting some rustflags as well

Comment: Does passing this flag with `$RUSTDOCFLAGS` work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249072/discussion-between-netwave-and-aleksander-krauze).